# Является ли exit(1) крашем программы?

Tags: c++

Можно ли вызов `exit(1);` назвать падением приложения? При условии вызова `exit(1);` в любое время выполнения?

Comment: exit (0) - краш программы. в теории, если вы пропишите его после определенной команд программа закроется.

Comment: @Evgeny_L Эм.. Что за бред?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это не философский вопрос, предназначение этой функции четко документировано. Ее вызов приводит к (частичной) подчистке ресурсов, вызове обработчиков, установленных через `atexit` и возврату в систему. Причем передача кода 0 или `EXIT_SUCCESS` говорит об успешном выходе, а `EXIT_FAILURE` о неуспешном. Если "произвольно написать в любом месте", то наверное можно и краш получить, но это не из-за функции, а из-за ее неправильного использования (т.е. вызывать ее надо тогда, когда подчистка и обработчики нормально сработают).

Крашем является вызов `abort()`, предназначение которой - немедленное аварийное завершение программы. На многих системах это по-умолчанию приводит к генерации дампа и т.д.

Comment: тоесть неуспешное завершение программы != краш ?

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh Конечно. Допустим утилита cp не смогла скопировать файл, потому что неправильный путь - завершается неуспешно. А если она упала начав читать за пределами строки - это краш.

Comment: в итоге программа завершается не успешно , можно ли считать что программа завершённая не успешно является крашом ?

Comment: @MaxKrugovykh Краш является неуспешным завершением, но не каждое неуспешное завершение является крашем. Собственно `int main(){ return EXIT_FAILURE; }` всегда завершается неуспешно, но никогда крашем.

Comment: я понял спасибо :)

Comment: При контролируемом аварийном завершении (`exit(code);`) желательно использовать коды, определенные в [sysexits.h](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3/sysexits/)

Answer (score 4):

В теории выполнение команды exit(1); в любом месте программы закончит выполнение данной программы на том моменте на котором написана команда. По моему мнению это нельзя назвать крашем.